# Why show a different on console and textbox

Tags: c#

I'm trying to grab a text from html page using HtmlAgilityPack. here is my code

```
var headers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2");
if (headers != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode item in headers)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(item.InnerText);
        Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText);
        }
}
```

It show different results on the console and the textbox.

result on console:

```
Avril
Lavigne
```

result on textBox:

```
AvrilLavigne
```

I want it like:

```
Avril Lavigne
```

I can't figure out what the character between two words.

*The original text on the html is : **Avril Lavigne** there is already space between Avril and Lavigne. but it does not on textbox.*

Comment: How many HTMLNodes are in the headers var?

Comment: Why you don't append " " too in for loop?

Comment: And use write not writeline and you got same output.

Comment: @neiiic same result on `Console.write`
the original text on the html is : Avril Lavigne there is already space between Avril and Lavigne. but it does not on textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine` write your input and then add `Environement.NewLine` after it.

You can use

```
var headers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2");
if (headers != null)
{
   textBox1.AppendText(string.Join(' ', headers.Select(item => item.innerHTML)));
}
```

Which will join each of you item.innerHTML and adding a space in between.

Comment: the original text on the html is : **Avril Lavigne** there is already space between Avril and Lavigne. but it does not on textbox. I got an error on your code. `A local or parameter named 'item' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter`

Comment: @JumRemdesk see edit. I bet you put my line inside the foreach loop didn't you ?

Comment: I'm sorry. I did. but after corrected the code give me the same result start with *AvrilLavigne* (no space between words) Please note I'm very beginner to HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: @JumRemdesk no problem. What if you add `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(' ', headers.Select(item => item.innerHTML))` inside the `if`?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(' ', headers.Select(item => item.innerHTML))` I added inside of `if` command. i got these errors `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'char' to 'string'
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string'` so i replace single quote with double quote. `innerHTML` gives html code so I used `InnerText` it gives all h2 tags text. but still no space.

Comment: @JumRemdesk ok. What's the value of `headers[0].innerHTML` ?

Comment: `<a name="Avril Lavigne"></a><img src="/images/artist.gif" hspace="5" nosave="" height="55" width="49">AvrilLavigne`

Comment: @JumRemdesk do you realize that there is no space in your input?

Comment: finally i god an answer `textBox1.AppendText(item.InnerText.Replace("\n"," "));`

Comment: yes. it's not a space. it's a new line. thank you Thomas helping me. i'm very appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding all of the text elements to an array and then pass that array to

```
var arr = new List<string>();
    foreach(var item in items){
arr.Add(item.InnerText);
}
textBox1.AppendText(string.Join(" ", arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TextBox` control's `AppendText` method just appends whatever string you pass to it to the end of the control's `Text` property.  The `Console` class's `WriteLine` method appends the string you pass to it to the console, and then it appends the end of line characters, that is, a carriage return & line feed.

If you want your text in the `TextBox` and in the console to be separated with spaces, you'll have to construct it yourself:

```
bool isFirst = true;
foreach (HtmlNode item in headers)
{
    string textToAppend = (isFirst ? string.Empty : " " ) + item.InnerText;
    isFirst = false;
    textBox1.AppendText(textToAppend);
    Console.Write(textToAppend);
}
```

In this case, `Console.Write` just outputs the string you pass to it without adding any end of line characters.